# how to get main tableview index in nested tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in swift and I am not able to get main tableview index on nested tableview button click

my code is like this

```
extension Section2QuestionsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrFinancialYears.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let strCellID = "Section2QuestionCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
        if cell == nil
        {
            tableSection2.register(Section2QuestionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: strCellID)
            cell = tableSection2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
        }
        
        let dictAppStats =  arrFinancialYears[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
        cell?.lblQuestionTitle.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(dictAppStats?["question"] as? String ?? "")"

        cell?.arrCourses = [Any]()
        cell?.arrCourses = dictAppStats?["options"] as? [Any] ?? []
        
        cell?.tableInsideHeightConstraints.constant = CGFloat(28 * (cell?.arrCourses.count ?? 0))
        
        cell?.tableInside.reloadData()
        

        
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Inside tableview

```
extension Section2QuestionCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrCourses.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsideSection2QuestionCell", for: indexPath) as! InsideSection2QuestionCell
        
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let dictFeeStats = arrCourses[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
        cell.lblOption.text = dictFeeStats?["option_value"] as? String
        cell.btnOption.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.btnOption.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.lblAnswerKey.text = dictFeeStats?["answer_key"] as? String
        cell.lblQuestionId.text = dictFeeStats?["question_id"] as? String
        cell.lblAnswerId.text = dictFeeStats?["option_id"] as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Button Click

```
@objc func btnOptionClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell: InsideSection2QuestionCell = tableInside.cellForRow(at: index) as! InsideSection2QuestionCell

        let QuestionId = cell.lblQuestionId.text
        let AnswwerId = cell.lblAnswerId.text
        
        print(QuestionId as Any)
        print(AnswwerId as Any)
        
        Globalnewdict = ["option":AnswwerId as Any,"question":QuestionId as Any]
        Globalindexvalue = sender.tag
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disconnectPaxiSockets"), object: nil)

       tableInside.reloadData()
    }
```

I am not able to get main tableview index path value on button. Is there is any way to get main tableview index path value on button click.

Please help
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You have table view cells that each contain a table view inside them?

Comment: You have a button in a tableview cell, and you want to get the indexpath of the cell when you click on that button, is that your purpose? If not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an index path object in your `Section2QuestionCell`

```
var parentTableIndexPath : IndexPath!
```

Then set the value in cellForRowAt tableview delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let strCellID = "Section2QuestionCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
    if cell == nil {
        tableSection2.register(Section2QuestionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: strCellID)
        cell = tableSection2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
    }
    cell.parentTableIndexPath = indexPath
    let dictAppStats =  arrFinancialYears[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
    cell?.lblQuestionTitle.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(dictAppStats?["question"] as? String ?? "")"
    cell?.arrCourses = [Any]()
    cell?.arrCourses = dictAppStats?["options"] as? [Any] ?? []
    cell?.tableInsideHeightConstraints.constant = CGFloat(28 * (cell?.arrCourses.count ?? 0))
    cell?.tableInside.reloadData()
    return cell!
}
```

Since btnOptionClick() is in same class, you can directly access the parent table Index path in your button action.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let strCellID = "Section2QuestionCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
        if cell == nil
        {
            tableSection2.register(Section2QuestionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: strCellID)
            cell = tableSection2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellID) as? Section2QuestionCell
        }
        
        let dictAppStats =  arrFinancialYears[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
        cell?.lblQuestionTitle.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(dictAppStats?["question"] as? String ?? "")"

        cell?.arrCourses = [Any]()
        cell?.arrCourses = dictAppStats?["options"] as? [Any] ?? []
        
        cell?.tableInsideHeightConstraints.constant = CGFloat(28 * (cell?.arrCourses.count ?? 0))
         cell?.tableInside.tag = indexPath.row
        cell?.tableInside.reloadData()
        

        
        return cell!
    }
```

In ButtonClick

```
@objc func btnOptionClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell: InsideSection2QuestionCell = tableInside.cellForRow(at: index) as! InsideSection2QuestionCell

        let QuestionId = cell.lblQuestionId.text
        let AnswwerId = cell.lblAnswerId.text
        
        print(QuestionId as Any)
        print(AnswwerId as Any)
        
        Globalnewdict = ["option":AnswwerId as Any,"question":QuestionId as Any]
        Globalindexvalue =  tableInside.tag
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disconnectPaxiSockets"), object: nil)

       tableInside.reloadData()
    }
```

In cellForRowAt I set indexpath.row to tableview.tag.
Then on button click I set tableview.tag to global indexpath.